# Migrating Intel XDK to other Framework

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I have have a mobile application project run by cordova with the help of Intel XDK framework. The issue is Intel XDK has limits.

My question is how do i migrate existing intel xdk project to another framework?
Do you have any framework suggestion?

I would love to hear some help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is Intel XDK has limited feature.

What do you mean?

Comment: like Currently, Intel XDK does not provide access to enabling or leveraging gradle scripts in applications via plugins.

Comment: Yes I noticed that when I tried to install the login with Facebook plugin, Although the Phonegap build supports gradle scripts but its a bit difficult to port your intel XDK project to a phonegap build, I now use Visual Studio 2015 with TACO, I build offline.

Comment: Cool, i just did it it manually this time. copy the www file and install the plugins. But still getting some cordova issues with regards to gradle version. Still figuring it out.